# SeekBar won't Update Runnable

Tags: android, multithreading

My SeekBar is not updating, I already confirmed that my runnable is running but the seekbar won't update.

Here is my code:

```
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mMediaPlayer != null && isSongPlaying) {
                    Log.i("Runnable", "I am Getting Called!");
                    int duration = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                    mSeekBar.setProgress(duration);

                }
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

This block of code is running but not updating the seekbar, what's the problem here?

[image: Log Cat]

Comment: I set the max value to the length of the song played from the array list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to update your SeekBar, you need get your current recording max duration and set it to your seek bar.

```
mSeekBar.setMax(mFileDuration);
```

Second, you need to update your SeekBar from a UI thread as such:

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
  if (mMediaPlayer != null && isSongPlaying) {
   Log.i("Runnable", "I am Getting Called!");
   int duration = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
   mSeekBar.setProgress(duration);

  }
  mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant update your UI in a different thread then the UI Thread. Calling a Handler creates a new thread which means that your Log output is visible but updating the View (Seekbar) is not.

Us an AsyncTask for that case, RXJava for simpler use, or run the Handler on the Ui/Main Thread using

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Or you can run it straight into your Main Thread like:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
   if(mMediaPlayer != null && isSongPlaying) {
                Log.i("Runnable", "I am Getting Called!");
                int duration = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                mSeekBar.setProgress(duration);

    }
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}
});
```

Comment: Uhh, Thanks for answering but how can I fix this.

Comment: ;-) Just updated a second before you wrote a comment

Comment: @MuhammadRayyanSiddiqui Please accept an answer if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**try this update your seekbar from UI Thread like below code**

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
 //Make sure you update Seekbar on UI thread
 YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {   

 @Override
    public void run() {
        if(mMediaPlayer != null && isSongPlaying) {
                Log.i("Runnable", "I am Getting Called!");
                int duration = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                mSeekBar.setProgress(duration);

            }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```